# Get the Max number of rows by ID

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I got a table **anonym** that look like this:

```
ID     anonyfield1     anofield2   someNumber
111     left            test          1
111     right           test          1
111                     ok            
222     left            ok            
222     left                          1
222     right           ok            2
222     right           ok            2
```

I want to get the highest numbers of row/result by ID in this table, for instance the result would be 4 here, because the ID 222 has 4 row.

I can't figure out how I can get this result by using a query SQL, so I would like some help plz :)

By the way I use pgsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) 
from anonym
where id = (select max(id) from anonym)
```

Comment: Damn, that work! thx very much, I should have asked earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use limit:

```
select id, count(*)
from anonym
group by id
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

This will guarantee that you only get one result.

If you only want the count(*), you can use:

```
select count(*)
from anonym
group by id
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

You can `group by` a column not present in the `select` list.